# How to pass session using HTTP Foundation from Controller Class into Chat Class in Ratchet Websocket?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, ratchet, symfony-http-foundation

I want to pass the session into the Chat class so I can use the user_id as the reference of the user who sent a message. I tried everything but I still had the session value empty.

**Server.php** ( Ratchet Server)

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create a session storage
$sessionStorage = new NativeSessionStorage();

// Initialize the session
$session = new Session($sessionStorage);
$session->start();

$chat = new Chat($session);

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            $chat
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

**Login.php** (Controller)

```
    public function validateInput()
    {
        $errors = [];
        $userModel = new Users;

        // Create a session storage
        $sessionStorage = new NativeSessionStorage();

        // Initialize the session
        $session = new Session($sessionStorage);
        $session->start();

        foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $errors[$field] = ucfirst($field) . " is required!";
            }
        }

        $check = $userModel->first($_POST);

        if ($check) {
            $email_address = $check->email_address;
            $password = $check->password;

            if ($_POST["password"] == $password) {

                // Set a session variable
                $session->set('user_id', $check->user_id);
                $session->set('email_address', $email_address);
                $session->set('is_logged_in', true);


                http_response_code(200);
                echo json_encode(['success' => 'Login successful!']);
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $errors[$field] = "Incorrect username or password.";
        }

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            http_response_code(400);
            echo json_encode(['errors' => $errors]);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

**Chat.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    protected $clients;
    protected $session;
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->model = new \Models\Messages;
        $this->session = $session;

        echo "Server started!";
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        // Access the user_id from the session
        $userId = $this->session->get('user_id');

        echo "User ID: $userId\n";


        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');

        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf(
            'Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n",
            $from->resourceId,
            $msg,
            $numRecv,
            $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's'
        );

        $userId = $this->session->get('user_id');
        $data = json_decode($msg, true);

        echo $userId;

        $message = [
            "user_id" => $data["user_id"],
            "message" => $data["message"],
            "sent_date" => date("d-m-y h:i:s")
        ];

        $this->model->insert($message);

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from == $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }



    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this or any approach you recommended when using Ratchet Websocket?

I tried to set a session in the Login Controller in the **validateInput** method

```
public function validateInput(){ ... }
```

But in **Chat.php** when I use the get function to fetch the user_id but the value is empty when I try to echo it

```
$userId = $this->session->get('user_id');
```